# Automatic build with source control monitoring

Tags: vb.net, svn, deployment, build, visual-sourcesafe

I am using SourceSafe 2005, and I have a project in VB.NET Framework 4.

What I want is a way to automate the build process and hopefully integrate easy deployment. I'd like to be able to send an automated notification when a build is made that lists the comments of the SourceSafe check-in's in the body of the message.

I've looked at a few options and some of them are confusing. I've seen it implemented with SVN, nAnt and CruiseControl, but it looks like it might take ages to set up being a novice of the aforementioned technologies.

What would be the easiest way to set something like this up in your opinion?

If I have to start using SVN for this, then that would also be a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) It supports SourceSafe and building of SLN's or via MSBUILD.

Comment: I have since started using TeamCity and find it a great tool. It's doing all the things I mentioned and has been working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple build and maybe a deployment to the first environment, you should be able to use any number of tools including free ones like CC.Net and team level CI solutions like Sylvanaar mentioned.

If the deployment gets trickier, my company's tools ([urbancode.com](http://urbancode.com)) could be more appropriate as we focus pretty hard on the "what comes after the build" part of CI.

As an aside, VSS is a pretty terrible place to store your source code (I've heard it called 'visual source shredder' by multiple clients). Microsoft's new TFS is better, as is Subversion (and many, many others). You do not need to switch source control to implement build and deploy. Many CI tools have VSS integrations (you can find a list [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix)) but friends don't let friends use VSS.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the source control we use isn't my decision. I'm a big fan of SVN and it would be my source control of choice.